# JavaScript Tabulator: row-wise select-editorParams depending on the data of another cell in that row

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I am working with Tabulator 5.4.x in JavaScript to create a table where I tried to implement the following behaviour:

Let's assume a Tabulator table with two columns *Selection 1* and *Selection 2*. In each row, the user should be able to:

1. first choose from a value, either *a* or *b*, from a "select" editor (dropdown list).
2. Based on the selection in step 1, the user should choose between a value *1* or *2*, if the selection in step 1 was *a* or between a value of *3* or *4*, if the selection in step 1 was *b*. The corresponding values should also appear in a dropdown list.

In other words, the selected value of the column named *Selection 1* chooses a subset from the selectable items *1*, *2*, *3* and *4* of the column named *Selection 2*

Do we have the possibility in Tabulator to achieve that behaviour? I have tried a *cellEdited* callback to modify the *editorParams* object, but it changes the whole *editorParams* object of the column and not only for that specific row.

To showcase this, I have implemented a small example in the following JavaScript code:

```js
var data = [
        { id: 1, sel1: "a", sel2: "1" },
        { id: 2, sel1: "b", sel2: "3" },
    ]
    var table = new Tabulator("#table", {
        columns: [
            {
                title: "Selection 1",
                field: "sel1",
                editor: "select",
                editorParams: {
                    values: ["a", "b"],
                }
            },
            {
                title: "Selection 2",
                field: "sel2",
                editor: "select",
                editorParams: {
                    /*
                    Only possible to define the whole list [1, 2, 3, 4] or one subset 
                    for the selection of "a" in column 1.
                    */
                    values: ["1", "2"],
                }
            },

        ],
        data: data
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to dig a bit deeper into the documentation of tabulator and I managed to implement the behaviour described above using the built in select editor for both columns and by specifying `editorParams` for the column named *Selection 2* as a function that returns the filtered list of options based on the selection of the column named *Selection 1*.

Full working example:

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.4.2/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.4.2/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <button id="download-csv">Download CSV</button>
    <button id="add-row">Add row</button>
    <div id="table"></div>
</body>

</html>

<script>

    let table = new Tabulator("#table", {
        columns: [
            {
                title: "Selection 1",
                field: "sel1",
                editor: "select",
                editorParams: {
                    values: ["a", "b"],
                },
            },
            {
                title: "Selection 2",
                field: "sel2",
                editor: "select",
                editorParams: function(cellProxy) {
                    let cell = Object.assign({}, cellProxy);
                    let row = cell._cell.row;
                    const id = row.data.id;
                    var values = ["1", "2"]
                    if(cell._cell.row.data.sel1 === "b") {
                        values = ["3", "4"]
                    }
                    return { values: values}
                }
            },
        ],
    });

    document.getElementById("add-row").addEventListener("click", function () {
        const id = table.getRows().length + 1;
        table.addData({ id: id, sel1: "a", sel2: 1 });
    });

    document.getElementById("download-csv").addEventListener("click", function () {
        table.download("csv", "data.csv");
    });

    table.on("tableBuilt", function () {
        table.addData({ id: 1, sel1: "a", sel2: 1 });
        table.addData({ id: 2, sel1: "a", sel2: 1 });
    })

</script>
```